# Outputting Dynamic Results in Abaqus

Tags: abaqus

I ran a dynamic simulation in Abaqus 6.11, and need a way to output the results in an efficient manner. I would like to report the velocity (among other quantities) of all the nodes at all time steps. In the GUI I could create a field output and select each step one at a time to report, but this approach is not practical. Does anyone know how to do this? In the end I'm hoping to get one/multiple rpt files containing the data I need. Then I can write a script in Matlab for reading/performing operations with the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a script to automate the process for you. Since Abaqus exposes interface for writing Python scripts, you should try that out.

If you've never done something like that, then create a field report for one step/frame manually and then open abaqus.rpy file to see the code necessary to create that single output. Once you figure out how to do it for one step, write a script with a loop to do it for all steps.

When you open abaqus.rpy file, there will probably be a lot of code, depending on how much commands you had previously issued. The like you need to look for looks something like

```
session.writeFieldReport(some parameters...)
```

The script you write can be run via 'File > Run script'.

If you need actual help writing the script, maybe you should open a question with specific problem.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect for what I need. Follow up question. So my code so far looks like:                                                                                             for i in range(1500):
session.writeFieldReport(
    fileName='C:/Temp/Dynamic Particles(Same)(1-29-15)/Velocity(t=1).rpt', 
    append=ON, sortItem='Node Label', odb=odb, step=0, frame=i, 
    outputPosition=NODAL, variable=(('V', NODAL), ))                                      In this code how do I update the t=1 in the filename to update with the for loop. For example, i = 1 t = 1, i = 2 t = 2,...etc.

Comment: You should use string formatting, either using modulo syntax or `format` function. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format